# JAXB unmarshalling a xml with inclusions

Tags: jaxb

I have a xml below called “TheFile.xml”

```
    <!DOCTYPE page [
      <!ENTITY class_common SYSTEM "class_common.xml" >]>

    <api xmlns:denp="http://intranet.denali.com/wiki/DocBook_profiling">

    &class_common;
```

As you can see the line above refers to another xml file called “class_common.xml” . However, when I do

```
    cl = class_xml.ObjectFactory.class.getClassLoader();
    context = JAXBContext.newInstance("class_xml", cl);
    Unmarshaller u = context.createUnmarshaller();
    api = (Api) u.unmarshal(new FileInputStream(classXMLFile));
```

I get some error like the following. Did I miss anything? Thanks

Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:

```
[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 8; columnNumber: 17; External Entity: Failed to read external document 'class_common.xml', because 'file' access is not allowed due to restriction set by the accessExternalDTD property.]
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, here is the answer, the Java code needs to be like the following

```
    cl = class_xml.ObjectFactory.class.getClassLoader();
    context = JAXBContext.newInstance("class_xml", cl);
    Unmarshaller u = context.createUnmarshaller();

    SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();

    spf.setXIncludeAware(true);
    spf.setNamespaceAware(true);
    spf.setValidating(true); // Not required for JAXB/XInclude

    XMLReader xr = (XMLReader) spf.newSAXParser().getXMLReader();
    SAXSource source = new SAXSource(xr, new InputSource(new   
        FileInputStream(classXMLFile)));

    api = (Api) u.unmarshal(source);
```